Why does the NIV translate "κεχαριτωμένη" as "highly favoured" in Luke 1:28?
Luke 1:28:

Καὶ [And] εἰσελθὼν [having entered] πρὸς [to] αὐτὴν [her] εἶπεν [he said], Χαῖρε [Greetings], κεχαριτωμένη [full of grace / having been graced / highly favored], ὁ [the] Κύριος [Lord] μετὰ [with] σοῦ [you].

NIV:

The angel went to her [Mary] and said, ‘Greetings, you who are highly favored! The Lord is with you.’

In this question, I asked about how Catholics understand the Greek word "κεχαριτωμένη" in Luke 1:28, and Ken Graham provided a detailed answer from a Catholic point of view which explained why Catholics prefer to translate this as "full of grace".
However, the NIV does not follow this translation, instead translating it as "[you who are] highly favored".  What is the significance of the NIV choosing this specific translation and what is the linguistic or theological basis of their translation?

This question probably belongs on biblical hermeneutics.
